# Django allauth KeyError: u'facebook'

Tags: django, django-allauth

I followed the guide and my settings looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    ...
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (


    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',       
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)

SITE_ID = 1

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook':
       {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time'],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'}}
```

Added this to Urls(project urls):

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Then I added site in settings(test.domain.com) AND I created 'social application' with that site ID.

Then I include it into random html template and get this error:

```
Django Version: 1.9b1
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
u'facebook'
```

Exact template rendering error highlights this:

```
{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}
```

I reinstalled twice but cant figure out what I am missing.

Comment: did you manage to find the solution? I have a similar issue with {% provider_login_url "facebook" process="connect" %}.. which returns KeyError at /accounts/profile/ ...'facebook'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" process="login" %}"></a>`?